# Yii2 unable to get the submit button name in controller

Tags: php, controller, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am working on `yii2`. I  am trying to get the `submit button` name in my controller. Below  is  my view

```
<div class="form-group">
            <a class="btn btn-default" onclick="window.history.back()" href="javascript:"><i
                        class="fa fa-close"></i>
                Cancel</a>

            <?php if ($model->isNewRecord && in_array(Yii::$app->user->identity->access_level,['admin','manager'])) { ?>

                <?= Html::submitButton('Add' ,['class' => 'btn btn-success','name'=>'a']) ?>
                <?= Html::submitButton('Add & Send Quotation' ,['class' => 'btn btn-info','name'=>'s']) ?>
            <?php } elseif (!$model->isNewRecord && in_array(Yii::$app->user->identity->access_level,['admin'])) {?>
                <?= Html::submitButton('Update', ['class' =>'btn btn-warning']) ?>
            <?php }elseif (!$model->isNewRecord && in_array(Yii::$app->user->identity->access_level,['editor'])){?>

                <?php
                if ($model->reqStatus==\common\models\Accountant::$request_status_titles[0]
                    ||$model->reqStatus==\common\models\Accountant::$request_status_titles[2]
                )
                {

                    echo Html::submitButton('Verified', ['class' =>'btn btn-success','name'=>'v']);
                    echo Html::submitButton('Not-Verified', ['class' =>'btn btn-danger','name'=>'n']);
                }
                ?>

            <?php } elseif (!$model->isNewRecord && in_array(Yii::$app->user->identity->access_level,['manager'])){?>
                <?php
                if ($model->reqStatus==\common\models\Accountant::$request_status_titles[3])
                {
                    echo Html::submitButton('Signed',['class' =>'btn btn-primary','name'=>'g']);
                }
                elseif ($model->reqStatus==\common\models\Accountant::$request_status_titles[4])
                {
                    echo Html::submitButton('Follow-Up',['class' =>'btn btn-primary','name'=>'r']);
                }
                else{
                    echo Html::submitButton('Send Quotation',['class' =>'btn btn-primary','name'=>'q']);
                }
                ?>
            <?php } ?>
        </div>
```

In above code there are multiple `submit button` each with `name`. In my controller I want to get the name of `Html::submitButton('Verified', ['class' =>'btn btn-success','name'=>'v']);` this  and `echo Html::submitButton('Not-Verified', ['class' =>'btn btn-danger','name'=>'n']);` this button.

```
 if (isset($_POST['v'])) //verified
        {
            $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post());
            $model->reqStatus = Accountant::$request_status_titles[1];
            $model->callVerified = 1;
            $model->clientRef = 'CL-'.uniqid();
            if($model->save())
            {

                return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
            }
            return $this->render('update', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);

        }
        elseif (isset($_POST['n']))//not-verified
        {
            
            $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post());
            $model->reqStatus = Accountant::$request_status_titles[2];

            if($model->save())
            {

                return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
            }
            return $this->render('update', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
        else
        {
            if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
                return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
            }
            return $this->render('update', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
```

When  I execute it. I am able to see the `verified`  and `not verified` button. But when I click on any of them, it doesn't go to the  `if (isset($_POST['v']))` or `esleif (isset($_POST['n']))`part but hits the else part. This same thing I am doing at another controller which is working perfectly fine.

**Update 1**

As per `scaisEdge` comment I  have tried to `var_dump($_POST)` and below  is  the result

```
array(2) {
    ["_csrf-backend"]=> string(88) "xS7Ctb2C677HKQJjoBL2SPznK3IHVGUDSn7MGhMs9SigHov36PSI7J9OewzkSJ0AzpBYN0A_KTIlEIZfd1qiYQ=="
    ["Bookkeeping"]=> array(43) {
        ["name"]=> string(5) "Laeeq"
        ["conNumb"]=> string(11) "03464394600"
        ["email"]=> string(15) "laeeq@gmail.com"
        ["location"]=> string(12) "Amber Valley"
        ["reqConcerns"]=> string(22) "UK_limited_partnership"
        ["workStart"]=> string(21) "PROJECT_START_2_MONTH"
        ["businessName"]=> string(27) "Retail_consumer_merchandise" 
        ["reqPurpose"]=> string(40) "Select between several bookkeeper quotes" 
        ["bookAssign"]=> string(16) "One_time_project"
        ["bookkRequire"]=> string(32) "Only local bookkeepers can quote"
        ["bookWork"]=> string(15) "Annual accounts"
        ["companyName"]=> string(22) "NONPROFIT_ORGANIZATION"
        ["turnOver"]=> string(17) "£300,000-600,000"
        ["info"]=> string(7) "Testing"
        ["remarks"]=> string(15) "Client Verified"
        ["annualConf"]=> string(0) ""
        ["personalTaxRetHrmc"]=> string(0) ""
        ["mPaySlip"]=> string(0) ""
        ["mRtiPenRet"]=> string(0) ""
        ["annualAcc"]=> string(0) ""
        ["annualCorpTaxRet"]=> string(0) ""
        ["annualCorpTaxRetHrmc"]=> string(0) ""
        ["qVatRet"]=> string(0) ""
        ["qBookMtd"]=> string(0) ""
        ["insuranceHmrc"]=> string(0) ""
        ["corpTaxPlan"]=> string(0) ""
        ["persTaxPlan"]=> string(0) ""
        ["businessAdvice"]=> string(0) ""
        ["fedTax"]=> string(0) ""
        ["provTax"]=> string(0) ""
        ["invPerM"]=> string(0) ""
        ["invPerMPrice"]=> string(0) ""
        ["add1"]=> string(0) ""
        ["add2"]=> string(0) ""
        ["add3"]=> string(0) ""
        ["add4"]=> string(0) ""
        ["add5"]=> string(0) ""
        ["add6"]=> string(0) ""
        ["add7"]=> string(0) ""
        ["add8"]=> string(0) ""
        ["add9"]=> string(0) ""
        ["add10"]=> string(0) ""
        ["remarks2"]=> string(0) "" 
    }
}
```

There is no `v` string in the above result.

I must be missing something that I don't know.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: try check the real content of $_POST  .. using var_dump($_POST) in controller

Comment: @scaisEdge you can check my `update  1`

Comment: @scaisEdge the string `v` is not there

Comment: but you have the name `n` ..  ?  .if you have just one of the two this is correct for your code  ..  an item can have just one name  ..

Comment: @scaisEdge If I click on the `verified` button then the name passed should be `v` and if I click on the `not verified` button then the name passed should be `n`. In both cases, it's not happening.

Comment: @scaisEdge this same mechanism is  working on other forms and  controllers but not this one :|

Comment: in your var_dump you have not an entry for the button name this mean that the code in your form don't contain an elem with name v or n..  could be your rendering in form is not as you expected ...

Comment: @scaisEdge Then what should I do to check the form ?

Comment: @scaisEdge The `Add` and  `Add & Send quotation` buttons are working perfectly fine as  both of the buttons are rendering the `Create Controller` but all the other buttons are rendered at `Update Controller`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin() ?>
```

Are you using this, before starting your form and ending it?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is very difficult to read so you need to refactor it for simplicity.
If I understand correctly, you have some conditions and you want different submit buttons to appear.

The first thing is none of the conditions require user input, so you can simply do the logic in the model.

For example

`$model->isNewRecord && in_array(Yii::$app->user->identity->access_level,['admin','manager']`

Does not require user input, so you can handle this in the model side.

Answer (score 0):

I think that @Lionel Yeo is right. Your code is too complicated. It should be separated in many views, controller actions.
Another option is that you can use Yii generated html links with GET parameters. If I read your code right..

If you want to see the incoming POST data.. - Just print *Yii::$app->request->post()* in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, it seemed to be causing it because I was using this

```
'enableClientScript' => false,
```

in ActiveForm::begin()

Answer (score -1):

the main problem is that you do not send a value back to the name.

Check out this answer:

[Send value of submit button when form gets posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22579616/send-value-of-submit-button-when-form-gets-posted)

in short your html markup should look like this:

```
<button type="submit" name="submit" value="Signed">Signed</button>
<button type="submit" name="submit" value="Follow-Up">Follow-Up</button>
```

In Yii2 view:

```
Html::submitButton('Signed',['class' =>'btn btn-primary','name' => 'submit', 'value' =>'Signed'])
```

In Yii2 controller:

```
if(Yii::$app->request->post('submit') === 'Signed') {
```

Comment: I have to submit it twice :|

Comment: Hi @Moeez, you are right my answer was not good. In your case there should be an empty string value in $_POST. Maybe you could add a little bit more details to your question, at least the form start, end tag. Maybe you could check browser developer tool for the post information. (chrome - F12 - network tab - push submit button - select your request - headers - form data)